# Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The error is as the title says.  I've also been actively looking for other questions with similar issues, but I don't seem to be able to fix this one. Most people were using the v7 dependencies and were instructed to change it into androidx, but my dependencies are already up to date ( from what I can see). So what's the issue?

XML File - activity_recycler_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".RecycleView">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'

    // ExoPlatyer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.4'

    // RecycleView
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navigation, PID: 26455
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navigation/com.example.navigation.RecycleView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.navigation:layout/activity_recycler_view: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.navigation:layout/activity_recycler_view: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.navigation:layout/activity_recycler_view: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.navigation:layout/activity_recycler_view: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.navigation:layout/activity_recycler_view: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

And the error hits right at the setContentView point

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo in your post but it is spelled : `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecycleView`  instead of `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` you're missing an **r**

Answer (score 0):

the class name is **RecyclerView** not RecycleView,

your xml code should be:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```